# | grep: can't open | grep: can't open grep

Tags: linux, bash

```
FILTER="grep -w PROD | grep -v PROD_OPL"

if (/usr/ucb/ps auxww | grep $1/$2 | $FILTER > /dev/null)
then
  #do something
fi
```

gives output:

```
grep: can't open |
grep: can't open grep
grep: can't open -v
grep: can't open PROD_OPL
grep: can't open |
grep: can't open grep
grep: can't open -v
grep: can't open PROD_OPL
```

How can i fix this? `$FILTER` needs to be dynamic.

Comment: Your filter won't work anyway : `grep -w PROD` wouldn't match "PROD_OPL" (because `_` is considered a word character), so the `grep -v PROD_OPL` always is a NO-OP (edit : I'm wrong actually, it would work if you're getting all lines that contains the word PROD but not PROD_OPL ; you just shouldn't expect it to get the lines containing only a word `PROD_something`)

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) to start. Short answer: a variable is not the appropriate place to store arbitrary *commands*; a function is.

Comment: Did you mean to use square brackets for your `if`?  I've never seen parens for `if`s in bash, and my simple test doesn't like them either.

Comment: @StephenNewell The parentheses are harmless, but unnecessary. The exit status of the subshell is just the exit status of the pipeline that runs in it.

Comment: @0x5453 Not quoting `$FILTER` is wrong, but quoting `$FILTER` is also wrong here. (In other words, using `FILTER` here is wrong.)

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "dynamic": does the entire *pipeline* need to be configurable, or can we assume it will always be a series of `grep` statements, for example? Is `FILTER` supposed to be set by user input (which is a *bad* idea)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store commands for later use, you will want to use a function.

Here's a basic example which will execute your two specific `grep` commands :

```
function filter() { 
    grep -w PROD | grep -v PROD_OPL
}

if (/usr/ucb/ps auxww | grep $1/$2 | filter > /dev/null)
then
  #do something
fi
```

The output of `grep $1/$2` is piped to the input of the function, which passes it to its pipeline, the output of which passes to the output of the function.

The return code of the function is left implicitly as the one of its last command, so the `if` condition will be true only if the filter matched some lines.

As far as dynamism goes, the function can be redefined at any point, so you can redefine your filter as needed. A better solution though would probably be to parametrize that function so that it implements the desired filter as needed.

I'd need more input to provide an adequate function (or maybe even a sufficient `grep` command, regex can be powerful...) but you could imagine a function which filter lines containing none of the parameters prefixed by `!` and all of the others.

Comment: This is *probably* the right answer, but it may not address the OP's need for `filter` to be "dynamic".

Comment: @chepner I agree, hence the "basic example" disclaimer. I'll see if I can provide some generic guidance before OP answers your request for clarification.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the many errors occur because bash is unable to interpret the `|` as a pipe, as it is just a character inside of `FILTER`. You thus need to actually evaluate `$FILTER` as an expression. For example, try

```
FILTER="grep -w PROD | grep -v PROD_OPL"

if /usr/ucb/ps auxww | grep $1/$2 | eval "$FILTER" > /dev/null
then
  #do something
fi
```

#### Edit

As stated clearly in various comments: This is most probable not the way you ought to solve your problem. Executing strings as code is bad and possibly dangerous design.
That said, if you have total control of the content of `FILTER`, it *can* be a nice and easy hack.

Comment: Correct, as far as it goes, but bad design.

Comment: The problem is, if `FILTER` is user input, you can't really trust the contents. If `FILTER` *isn't* user input, you should be using a function instead.